# Calcular las transcurridos de una fecha o otra fecha en Mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

Quisiera saber si esta bien las horas transcurridos entre esta dos fechas.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2020-05-11 17:33:00','2020-05-12 19:26:17') as horas from altavehiculos WHERE idVehiculo = 1 ;
```

Resultado que me dio es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me quede con la duda no debería salir como resultado: 26:53:17

Comment: Para empezar tienes los valores al revés, pues primero debe ir la fecha mas antigua y luego la mas reciente, por otro lado no veo por que el resultado deba ser 26:53:17

Comment: Porque lo corrobore en linea y me dio ese resultado 26:53:17